# SSD persistent disk fails to mount following reboot of Ubuntu 14.04 instance

Tags: ubuntu, google-compute-engine, mount

I have 1 instance in europe west 1b running `Ubuntu 14.04` and it has another persistent disk (same region & zone) connected. I completed the mount instructions here
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk and was able to format, mount and read.write to and from the persistent ssd disk.

When I shutdown the instance and start it up, I have to access the serial console to complete the boot as the serial console output as SSH hasn't started and the serial console says

```
> Starting enable remaining boot-time encrypted block devices The disk
> drive for "google-[My_DISK_NAME] is not ready yet or not present keys:
> Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

If I access the serial console and run `sudo fdisk -l` it doesnt show the persistent disk but I can re(mount) it using the command `sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/disk/by-id/google-[DISK_NAME] /mnt/disks/[MNT_DIR]` and access the content again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mea culpa there was an extra space in my mount disk command I added to fdisk